# How to do weighted average on a timeseries groupby bucket

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My timeseries dataframe looks like below:

```
ts_ms            a.       b.       c.       flow.    latency.    duration
1614772770705.   10.      10.      4.       1           2          3
1614772770800.   10.      10.      2.       1           2          4
1614772770750.   10.      5.       4.       1           2          3
```

I need to create a 5Min bucket, then groupby `a,`, `b`, `c` such that `latency` is summed and `duration` is weighted averaged on `flow`

What I have so far is

```
wm = lambda x: (x * df.loc[x.index, "flow"]).sum() / df.flow.sum()

def agg_func(df):
    df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5Min')).agg(latency_sum=("latency", "sum"), duration_weighted=("duration", wm))

#convert to datetimes
df['ts_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts_ms'])
df.set_index('ts_date', inplace=True)

df1 = df.groupby(["a", "b", "c"]).apply(agg_func)
```

That does now work. I basically get an empty dataframe as `df1`

What am I missing? Please suggest.

EDIT

For clarity, the expected output dataframe should have below columns with some values ...

```
ts_date            a.       b.       c.       latency_sum    duration_weighted
```

But I get an empty dataframe

```
df1.to_dict('records')

[]
```

Comment: kindly provide the expected output. Also if you can share both input and output dataframes as dictionary : ``df.to_dict('records')``

Comment: @sammywemmy please see the edits

Comment: @nad What's the desired output?

Comment: @nad see this post on creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's hard to know what is going on if we can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @nad Check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to also `return`:

```
wm = lambda x: (x * df.loc[x.index, "flow"]).sum() / df.flow.sum()

def agg_func(df):
    return df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5Min')).agg(latency_sum=("latency", "sum"), duration_weighted=("duration", wm))

#convert to datetimes
df['ts_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts_ms'])
df.set_index('ts_date', inplace=True)

df1 = df.groupby(["a", "b", "c"]).apply(agg_func)
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
                             latency_sum  duration_weighted
a  b  c ts_date                                            
10 5  4 1970-01-01 00:25:00            2           1.000000
   10 2 1970-01-01 00:25:00            2           1.333333
      4 1970-01-01 00:25:00            2           1.000000
```